# How to merge Designer and XAML editors in one window in Visual Studio?

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, xaml, designer

How to merge Designer and XAML editors in one window (designer on top of xaml editor) in Visual Studio 2010 when working with WPF project?

Currently, to switch between them I need to use tabs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the toggle button in the picture below.

[image: Visual Studio WPF designer]

Answer (score 1):

There are three tabs above the output toolbar: "Design", an image with two arrows and "XAML". Click on the image (the second tab). In that way, you can switch - if you want the code to be above or under the design editor.